# Where to change objects prototypes in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, prototype

I want to add or override some standard methods of Object, Function and Array (e.g., like suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307264/what-object-javascript-function-is-bound-to-what-is-its-this/14309359#14309359)) in node.js application. How should I do all the "patches" in just one module so that it affects all my other modules?

Will it be enough if I do it in a module that is just `require`'d or it won't work because the two modules have different global namespaces so they have different Object?... Or should I run some initialisation function after `require` that makes all these "patches" working in this module too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each file loaded shares the same primordial objects like Object, Array, etc, unless run in a different vm Context, so requiring the file once in your initialization will make the changes everywhere.

Comment: Do you mean that it's even enough to require this module with "patches" once, only in my main module, and I don't need to require it in every module I want to have Object&co "patched"?

Comment: Yes, it's enough to require it just once. All modules in node share the same global scope. They have a different *module* scope, but the same global scope. So they have the same `Object`, `Function`, `Array`, etc.

Comment: It works for Function.prototype and Array.prototype, but when I try to do it with Object.prototype it throws TypeError:

TypeError: Property description must be an object: undefined

    at Function.defineProperty (native)

    at Object.<anonymous> 

(/opt/nginx/html/dev.stockscompare/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:53:10)

Answer (score 14):

```
//require the util.js file 
require('./util.js');

var a = [];
a.doSomething();
```

in your "util.js" file:

```
//in your util.js file you don't have to write a module, just write your code...
Array.prototype.doSomething = function(){console.log("doSomething")};
```