# Which is the most elegant way to extend a native object in a NodeJS project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module, solid-principles

I have a NodeJS project that uses BigInt for its model's ids. I also have a WebSocket where I sent serialized objects to a client. The problem with BigInt is that it is not serializable like other objects (Boolean, Number, etc). Therefore I use [MDN recommendation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#use_within_json) to define a global handler function the BigInt object.

```
BigInt.prototype.toJSON = function() { return this.toString()  }
```

I will use this in the entire app scope from now on.

**The question is where do I place this code so it is elegant and respects SOLID principles?**

I am looking for a good solution for kind of issue.

Currently it is placed in index.js like this:

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import logger from './middleware/logger';

const main = async () => {
  // where should I modularise BigInt extension
  BigInt.prototype.toJSON = function () {
    return this.toString();
  };

  app.use(cors());

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!');
  });

  app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port 3000!`));
};

main().catch((err) => {
  logger.error(err);
});
```

Comment: I think you can find a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329210/where-to-change-objects-prototypes-in-node-js) (the ./utils file solution)

Comment: If you want to respect the **S**ingle responsibility principle, then you don't place that thing in all `BigInt`s. Instead you give all your models a `toJSON` method; or even pass a custom serialiser into `JSON.stringify` in the places where you use it (and also a custom deserialiser into `JSON.parse` respectively, which might be more important even)

Comment: @Lykos94 Great reference, I think that would work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice for this kind of extension is to use the solution for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329210/where-to-change-objects-prototypes-in-node-js).

I've refactored the code like this.

utils.ts

```
(BigInt.prototype as any).toJSON = function () {
  return this.toString();
};
```

index.ts

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import logger from './middleware/logger';
import "utils.ts" // <== this code gets executed, therefore BigInt extenstion is in the scope of project from now on

const main = async () => {
  app.use(cors());

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!');
  });

  app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port 3000!`));
};

main().catch((err) => {
  logger.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Don't use `(BigInt.prototype as any)`. Instead, declare the `toJSON` method on the `BigInt` interface.

Comment: Could you show an example or reference link?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58265985/extending-built-in-types-in-typescript