# Where is a function's this value stored?

Tags: javascript

I know that you can bind the this value of a function using

`function.bind(new_this_value, arguments)`

But is there a way to access the bound value? ie something like this:

```
console.log(my_function.boundValue)
```

In other words, suppose a module provides the following function:

```
function getACoolFunction () {
  var someFarAwayFunction = function() {console.log(this.name)}
  var bound_this_value = {name: "bound this value"}
  someFarAwayFunction.bind(bound_this_value)
  return someFarAwayFunction;
}
```

and I have this in my code:

```
import {getACoolFunction} from coolModule

var coolFunction = getACoolFunction();
// coolFunction.bound_value
```

How do I get the bound value of coolFunction from my code without changing the module?

Comment: You have access to both `new_this_value` and `arguments` before you pass them to `.bind()`

Comment: I guess I'm more interested in how the JS engine knows what the this value is and how to access it when debugging

Comment: Have you read the specification? What do you mean by "access it"?

Comment: So given a function, can you find the bound this value without calling the function

Comment: `this` is `new_this_value`. Do you mean where you cannot view `new_this_value`at the bound function itself?

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully be clearer

Comment: Given the edited Question, at first glance may not be possible without calling function.

Comment: No, this is not possible. Your best bet would be to overwrite `console.log` and just call the `coolfunction` to get the string. But really, if the object should be accessible, you should rewrite the module to make it accessible.

Comment: Missing `function()` at `someFarAwayFunction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from doing this:

```
let my_function = function.bind(new_this_value, arguments);
my_function.boundValue = new_this_value;
```

---

As from the [standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects), a bound function is:

> an exotic object that wraps another function object.

It has **internal properties** containing original function, provided `this` and arguments.
As they are explicitly mentioned as *internal*, I would say that they are not directly exposed and accessible.

---

Probably [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14307264/4987285) contains details that can help you to work around this limitation.

Comment: Sure but I'm wondering if there's a way to get new_this_value without defining your own property, particularly if you're debugging objects you didn't write for example