# can i check what a function is bound to?

Tags: javascript, web, this

`bind` in javascript lets you bind a function to some `value` and in the returned function has `this` equal to the `value`.

if I have a function, is there a way to check that `this` inside this function is already bound to a value ?
and to what value ?

--- adding example of what i want

```
function foo() { /*...*/ }

const bar = foo.bind(val); // val is any value
```

if am given only `bar` can i somehow reach to `val`

Comment: It's usually related to the context (whether the function is bound to a parent object or to the main context itself). In the global context, `this` in any function refers to `window`. Unless you are in strict mode, where `this` is undefined. You can find more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What object javascript function is bound to (what is its "this")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307264/what-object-javascript-function-is-bound-to-what-is-its-this)

Comment: thanks @AyushGupta , will close this one