# Why can't document methods be held in a function?

Tags: javascript, function, dom

In JavaScript, you can set variables to hold certain functions and use them, like so:

```
var log = console.log;
log('foo');
```

But for some strange reason, you can't do that on most if not all document methods, such as `querySelector`:

```js
var select = document.querySelector;

// causes the error: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
select('p');
```

```html
<p>...</p>
```

**Why is that, and is there a workaround for it?**

Comment: Because of `this`. Try with `var select = document.querySelector.bind(document);`; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context seems to get lost. It's not bound with the `document`. Use it this way:

```js
var select = document.querySelector.bind(document);
// Works!
console.log(select('p'));
```

```html
<p>...</p>
```

You can see what a function is bound to, in JavaScript: [What object javascript function is bound to (what is its "this")?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14307264).