# How execution context other than window object is moved in stack In Js

Tags: javascript

So the `this` of  function depends on its  execution context (place where its being called)

```
function foo(){
console.log(this) // will print window

}

foo()
```

And this one

```
const obj={
  fun:function(){

  console.log(this)
}
 
}
obj.fun(); //will print the obj
```

I am just confused how the execution context obj gets loaded to call stack from heap

[image]

Or am I missing something here ? .Please help me out

Comment: The value of `this` is not related to the execution context. It depends on *how* a function is called. [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)

Comment: @VLAZ I am referring men -https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Yes, and my comment stands - the execution context is not related at all to the value of `this`.

Comment: I know that question ,I am just wondering how things are working internally

Comment: It's simple, the value is always the caller unless you use bind(), call(), and apply(). If no caller is specified it's `window`. In case of func.bind(obj), the obj is wrapped by the bound function and upon call internally it calls function on the bound object. I found [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14307667/15273968) very useful. Modern classes are just syntactical sugar internally they expand to old style code in [babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Answer (score 2):

## Enclosing Scopes

Forgetting about `this` for a moment. The concept of "execution context" is called Closure in Javascript. The [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) explains it well.

To get a better sense of it, let's use a variable called `a` instead of `this` :

```
const a = 1;

function foo() {
  //can access `a` here
  function bar() {
    //can also access `a` here
  }
}
```

These functions have access to the outer scopes where they were declared. This is the **"execution context"**, as you called it, though this is the wrong terminology for Javascript. **"Scope"** or **"lexical scope"** would be the correct terms.

No matter where you call those functions, they will still be able to print `a`.

## Call Stack and Heap

The [MDN article on Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#closure_scope_chain) has this to say:

> Closure Scope Chain
> Every closure has three scopes:
>
> - Local Scope (Own scope)
> - Outer Functions Scope
> - Global Scope

The thing to note about these is that they are established at ***parse time***, ***NOT execution time***.

While Javascript does have a call stack and a heap, these have nothing to do with scope or closures. Scopes are a property of *the function*, and remain the same from the time the Javascript is first parsed until the code has finished running.

## About `this`

`this` is a variable that depends entirely on *how* the function was initialized and called. The [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) may again prove useful here.

Let's look again at your example function, with some inline comments and examples:

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this);
}

// Sure, calling `foo()` right now will print `window` if you're in a browser
foo(); //prints `window` in a browser

// But any use of `new` keyword will change `this` (including classes)
const obj = new Object(); 
obj.foo = foo;
obj.foo(); //prints `{ foo: [Function: foo] }`

// Similarly, assigning `foo` to a plain object will also change `this`
const obj = {}; 
obj.foo = foo;
obj.foo(); //prints `{ foo: [Function: foo] }`

// Lastly, any of the `Function.prototype` methods `bind`, `apply`, `call` 
// intentionally change `this`
//
// `bind()` returns a new function:
const boundFunction = foo.bind({"this is a property": "and a value, see!?"});
boundFunction(); //prints `{ 'this is a property': 'and a value, see!?' }`
//
//`apply()` and `call()` both execute the function 
// (the difference between the two is in how arguments are passed,
// see the MDN articles on 
// [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#syntax) and on
// [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#syntax) for more details)
foo.apply({bar:1}); //prints `{ bar: 1 }`
foo.call({baz: 2}); //prints `{ baz: 2 }`
```

Answer (score 2):

`This` in Javascript behaves differently in browser & Node env. this in global context points to window in browser and globalthis in Node. In this case 'This' is pointing on calling object, i.e obj. when a fn is being called js looks this in its lexical environment. You can also bind this context with apply,bind,call.

```
const obj = {name:'Irfan',fn:function(){console.log(this.name)}} // will print Irfan
```

Here this is pointing pointing to obj i.e this=obj(this.name=obj.name), but in arrow fn this is not bound by default.