# Re-bind function with new arguments to originally bound object

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to re-bind a function so that it is bound to the same object it was originally but accepts a different argument value?

For instance...

```
// Object definition
function OriginalOwner(prop) { this.prop = prop; }
OriginalOwner.prototype.aFunc = function(arg) { return this.prop + arg; }

// Object instance
var owner = new OriginalOwner("Returned ");

// Example function bindings
var boundFunc = owner.aFunc.bind(owner);
var reboundFunc = boundFunc.bind(boundFunc.owner, "myArgument");

// Calling rebound function
console.log(reboundFunc()); // outputs "Returned myArgument"
```

Comment: This code works, doesn't it?

Comment: @Bergi There is no owner property on `boundFunc`, but unintentionally this still works

Comment: Yes - you can pass anything you want (and should probably pass `null` to be explicit), as you cannot rebind a bound function. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/26545549/1048572 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/7282158/1048572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to **add** arguments, you can do that with `bind`. It doesn't matter what you supply for the first `bind` argument, because it will be ignored when you call `bind` on a bound function (so `null` is a reasonable choice for that first argument).

Because the first argument is ignored, your original code would work unchanged, but it would be misleading (`boundFunc` has no `owner` property, so `boundFunc.owner` yields `undefined`). But better to use `null` or something else to avoid misreading people reading the code later.

Only change is formatting and a missing `;`, plus the `***` line:

```js
// Object definition
function OriginalOwner(prop) {
  this.prop = prop;
}
OriginalOwner.prototype.aFunc = function(arg) {
  return this.prop + arg;
};

// Object instance
var owner = new OriginalOwner("Returned ");

// Example function bindings
var boundFunc = owner.aFunc.bind(owner);
var reboundFunc = boundFunc.bind(null, "myArgument"); // ***

// Calling rebound function
console.log(reboundFunc()); // outputs "Returned myArgument"
```

The *reason* that works is that `bind` returns a new function that will get called with the `this` we supply — but the bound function we're calling it on completely ignores the `this` you call it with, using the one **it** has bound to it instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the term "bound function" is used as "the method is bound to the receiver", not "the method has a receiver bound to it".

Comment: @Bergi: I"m not sure what you're trying to say there. A bound function has a specific `this` value bound to it. It's in the `[[BoundThis]]` internal slot - https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects.

Comment: I mean that a "bound function" is a function that is bound to an object, not the other way round (the object being bound to the function). Of course, ultimately they are "bound *together*" so probably both ways can be used, but imo the usage "the [[BoundThis]] that is bound to the BoundFunction instance" is weird.

Comment: @Bergi: Well, "the function has a specific `this` bound to it" makes sense and is literally true / fits with the spec, so it doesn't seem weird to me at all. But I do see what you're saying the other way around, too, FWIW.